# EF Core sets null when setting relations

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, entity-framework, uwp

I'm using entity framework core in my app. I have some relations in my tables. The problem is that when I set the relations  It saves the data, but when I want to read the data, that related fields are null :(
[image: Null]

Due to code limitations on Stackoverflow, I link the project you go and see full code on GH.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/mohsens22/QBox/blob/master/QBox/Model/SetNewQuestions.cs)

AND

[Here is the model](https://github.com/mohsens22/QBox/blob/master/QBox/Model/Model.cs)

I'll be so thankful if you help me.

EDIT:
Here is where I fill Data (line 140 to the end)
[The code](https://github.com/mohsens22/QBox/blob/master/QBox/QBox/Views/Settings.xaml.cs)

Comment: Try marking the navigation properties with `virtual`.

Comment: @EBrown I made them virtual in my last commit. But no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `.Include` like this

```
  public static List<Question> GetQuestion()
        {
            List<Question> x = new List<Question>();
            using (var db = new Model())
            {
                x=db.Questions.Include("Course").Include("Answer").ToList();
            }

            return x;
        }
```

you can also view this link for why i used `.Include` [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)